# $gcd(r,s)=1$ and $rs=a^2$

Tags: number-theory

Let $r$ and $s$ be positive integers. Show that if $gcd(r,s)=1$ and $rs=a^2$ for some an integer number $a$, then there exist integer numbers $b$ and $c$ such that $r=b^2$ and $s=c^2$.

Comment: How to how that if $gcd(r,s)=1$ and $rs=a^2$ for some an integer number $a$, then there exist integer numbers $b$ and $c$ such that $r=b^2$ and $s=c^2$.

Comment: This is a simple consequence of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic.

Comment: How to use the condition $gcd(r,s)=1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $r = \prod r_n^{a_n}$,and $s=\prod s_n^{b_n}$, where $r_n$ and $s_n$ are primes. By definition, $rs=\prod r_n^{a_n}s_n^{b_n}$ is in it's unique prime decomposed form. Since $\gcd(r,s)=1$, it follows that $r_i \neq s_j$ for any $i,j$ because such a prime would have to divide the $\gcd$ as well.

Furthermore, note that $rs$ is a perfect square, which implies that each of it's exponents, when it is expressed as a prime decomposition, is *even*. It follows that each of the $a_n$ and $b_n$ are even, because they are the exponents of the prime decomposition.

Now, note that $r=\prod r_n^{a_n}$ is also a perfect square, because above we deduced that each of it's exponents $a_n$ is even. Similarly, $s=\prod s_n^{b_n}$ is also a perfect square, because above we deduced that each of it's exponents $b_n$ is even.